# Input impedance of a round straight copper antenna

Tags: amplifier, resistors, antenna, impedance, math

I got some help from a discussion of yesterday about network impedance matching for transferring data between antennas ([Basic RF signal amplifier](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/668267/basic-rf-signal-amplifier)). The discussion was about that the current and the voltage gain of amplifiers are trivial. Important issue is the impedance between amplifier and antenna. I researched again and I have seen there are smart calculations to get the values for resistors of transistor-based amplifiers. Starting off from here was a little complicated, so messed up with the prepared calculators on internet. There are good ones. But my problem is with the antenna. It is 12.3 cm long and has 2 mm diameter, is copper and runs at 8 MHz. On a webpage of https://chemandy.com/calculators/round-wire-impedance-calculator.htm I gave in the information I predicted before and it resulted the following value:

Z = 0.01442 Ω + j 5.585232 Ω

The antenna is a shortened one. What can I do with this value? I need an amplifier that works with maybe common-emitter amplifier. From where can I start to calculate the needed resistors for impedance matching. Are there any good starter kits on internet I could council? There is also another webpage https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/interactive-design-tools/rf-impedance-matching-calculator.html about RF impedance matching as calculator. Is there a general way to make up a hacky experiment to make this more clearly?

Comment: I need some practical information, because I am near to realise a project at home and want to solder things together and finish this homework somehow. Thanks for help.

Comment: Any way you can make the antenna longer? The real part of Z is very low, which will make matching difficult.

Comment: If I must make the antenna longer, sure I will do it. What must it be at length at least?

Comment: That calculation is for a round wire more or less in free space, not an antenna specifically.  You appear to need an "electrically short dipole" calculator.  12cm is essentially no length at 8MHz -- expect to need much more.

Comment: I added to the wire a bobin of 220uH. It was enough for radio transmission but only when I am close to this 8 Mhz transmitter of 12.3cm length. I can take another bobin for less than 220uH, after this the antenna can be more than 12.3cm and the impedance will be that more, I suppose.

Comment: Does a shortened antenna deliver in much shorter distance than a fully featured antenna in free space? If yes, I should think of making the antenna longer. Right?

Comment: I short antenna (in relation to the wavelength of the signal) has very low radiation resistance. As a result, the ratio of power that actually gets radiated to the power that is wasted as heat is very low. That is, the smaller the antenna in relation to wavelength, the less efficient it is likely to be as a radiator, i.e. as an antenna. 8MHz signals have a wavelength in free space of about 38 meters. A quarter-wave antenna would thus be about 9.5 meters. A half-wave, about 19 meters. So, in your case, longer is definitely better. There might be a way around this, though, with looping.

Comment: Unfortunately, per Wikipedia "loops with a circumference smaller than about 1/10 
 wavelength become so inefficient they are rarely used for transmission." In your case, at 8MHz, 1/10 wavelength is still 3.8 meters circumference. Diameter is 1.21 meters. Is that a possibility for you? How far do you actually need to transmit?

Comment: I need to transmit for about 10 meters not more. How long must be the wire to get around this problem?

Comment: At this point, I think the question you should ask yourself is how big you can reasonably make the antenna, and then just live with the inefficiencies that your small antenna will have. You can make up for antenna inefficiency with more amplifier power. However, if you go with a loop 1.21 meters in diameter, we can calculate a matching network for an amplifier. I would select for the amplifier output stage a common collector, as this will have the lowest output impedance.

Comment: Thanks for help. As you said, I will think about making an efficient antenna. I do not think a shortened transmitter antenna can give me the needed power to make the transmission distance more. That was my error. Taking a quartz crystal of more than 8 Mhz will make the antenna shorter in the right way and this will make my life easier.

Comment: 10m distance at 8MHz is still near field; you don't necessarily need to radiate anything at all. Consider using an inductive loop or electric field plate(s) instead. Better yet, don't generate EMI but use an approved e.g. 2.45GHz radio (ZigBee, Bluetooth, even WiFi, etc.) instead, which is fully featured, can be more compact, and is well supported.

Comment: This is a classic X-Y problem: you have determined a potential solution Y to underlying problem X. But you have a poor understanding of the problem, which leads to strange questions. They are strange not because they haven't been asked before, but because there is a better question to be asked -- and a much more common one. Ask about your underlying problem X instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a discussion two or three years ago. [Very short range indoor RF transmitter - receiver circuits](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/524105/very-short-range-indoor-rf-transmitter-receiver-circuits)  It is less technical but satisfied me in that way. Shortened antennas have several technical disadvantages. I can now navigate through antennas better.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to transmit over 10m at 8MHz, this is less than a quarter of a wavelength.  All the antenna design stuff you are quoting is about radiation fields in the far field whereas you are in the near field. Forget radiation, your system will be dominated by simple capacitive or inductive coupling.  Inductive coupling is likely the easiest.  Make a couple of coils, maximize the current in the transmit coil (probably by resonance), and worry about the size and orientation of the receive coil and the sensitivity of the receiver.

Think 13MHz store security systems.

Answer (score 1):

An 8 MHz radio wave has a wavelength of about 38 meters in free space. A half-wave dipole antenna would be about 19 meters in length. A quarter-wave monopole antenna would be about 9.5 meters in length. A 1/10th wave small loop antenna would have a circumference of about 3.8 meters and a diameter of about 1.21 meters.

When antennas are significantly small relative to the wavelength of the signal they are attempting to radiate, then their efficiency generally drops. The radiation resistance of the antenna becomes very small, often a few m\$\Omega\$. As a result, the ratio of power that is radiated to the power that is converted to heat becomes small.

Since you only

> need to transmit for about 10 meters not more.

you will probably be able to get by with an poorly matched and hence inefficient antenna/amplifier combination. You can make up for the inefficiencies by using an amplifier with sufficient power.

The rest of this answer will discuss how you could drive a 1/10th wavelength loop antenna.

[It is important to note that small loop antennas radiate *parallel* to the plane of the loop, not perpendicular, as large loop antennas do. Check that the antenna is oriented properly before deciding the amplifier or antenna doesn't work].

According to [this loop antenna calculator](https://www.66pacific.com/calculators/small-transmitting-loop-antenna-calculator.aspx), a loop with a 3.85 meter circumference, and a 2 mm diameter wire, driven at 8 MHz, will have

- a radiation resistance of 20 m\$\Omega\$
- a loss resistance of 452 m\$\Omega\$
- a radiation efficiency of 4%
- an inductance of 1.08 uH
- a required tuning capacitance of 365 pF

(to be continued)

Comment: I have just seen a link on Internet, might be useful. "The VK1SV LF/MF Short Vertical Antenna calculator"<https://people.physics.anu.edu.au/~dxt103/calculators/Rrad.php> The question is, what can i do with those values. Give me clue about how I should operate them into the circuit.

Comment: I know LC circuits for oscillation, which requires inductor and capacitor. I calculated the values and they match with 8 Mhz. What if I use quartz crystal or are these values dedicated to antenna in order to make it work properly?